# Random.randint как сделать чтобы числа не повторялись

Tags: python, случайные-числа

диапазон random.randint от 1 до 7, нужно чтобы выдало две цифры из этого диапазона при этом чтобы они не были одинаковыми

Например я пишу:

```
import random

print(random.randint (1,7))
print(random.randint (1,7))
```

Нужно запретить чтобы высветились одинаковые числа (2 2, 5 5, и т.п.)

Comment: А когда чисел не останется, что делать?

Comment: Я выдаю диапазон random.randint от 1 до 7, нужно чтобы выдало две цифры из этого диапазона при этом чтобы они не были одинаковыми

Answer (score 8):

Вам нужна функция [`sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) из этой же библиотеки.

```
import random
random.sample(range(1,8), k=2) 
# 8, потому что range работает как slice и возвращает [1;8)
```

Возвращает list из k (в нашем влучае двух) уникальных элементов. Дальше делаете с ним, что нужно, или сразу раскладываете результат на переменные:

```
a, b = random.sample(range(1,8), k=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже вариант, только у меня чуть-чуть подлиннее:

```py
import random
a = random.randint (1,7)
b = random.randint (1,7)
while a==b:
    b = random.randint (1,7)
print(a,b)
```